# Flutter: How to make a custom avatar

Tags: flutter, user-interface, avatar

I want to make avatars that wrapped inside a smooth + customized shape that looks similar to  Xiaomi current's Logo (it is not a rectangle with some kind of Radius.elliptical(x,y) but rather a little bit more complicated function). Is there a way to do so efficiently?

[image]

Comment: check `ContinuousRectangleBorder` - the docs say: *"A rectangular border with smooth continuous transitions between the straight sides and the rounded corners."*

Comment: Alternatively you can also use custom paint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try with [ContinousRectangularBorder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/ContinuousRectangleBorder-class.html) as mentioned by @pkskink

[image]

1. Using ContinousRectangularBorder

```
Container(
  decoration: ShapeDecoration(
    shape: ContinuousRectangleBorder(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(95.0),
  ),
  color: Colors.orange[800]),
  height: 100,
  width: 100,
  alignment: Alignment.center,
  child: Text('Mi',
           style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 40),
         ),
),
```

[image]

2. Using the normal borderRadius  (For comparison)

```
Container(
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40.0),
    color: Colors.orange[800]),
  height: 100,
  width: 100,
  alignment: Alignment.center,
  child: Text(
  'Mi',
   style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 40),
 ),
),
```

And if you are not satisfied with this I would suggest using custom Paint which allows you to draw any kind of shapes